# Mysql insert multiple rows, if duplicate value column then update

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

I have a MySQL table that looks like this

```
id | customer_id | textkey | value |
---+-------------+---------+-------+
 1 |           1 | text1   | value1|
 2 |           1 | text2   | value2|
 3 |           1 | text3   | value3|
 4 |           1 | text4   | value4|
 5 |           2 | text1   | value1|
...
```

I want to insert the following values to `customer_id` 1

`(text1, valueX), (text3, valueY), (text5, value5), (text6, value6)`

The end result should look like this

```
mysql> SELECT * from MyTable where customer_id=1;

id | customer_id | textkey | value |
---+-------------+---------+-------+
 1 |           1 | text1   | valueX|
 2 |           1 | text2   | value2|
 3 |           1 | text3   | valueY|
 4 |           1 | text4   | value4|
 6 |           1 | text5   | value5|
 7 |           1 | text6   | value6|
```

The `value` column should update whenever there is a duplicate in the `textkey` insert, and insert regularly if the `textkey` is not a duplicate. What query could I use to achieve this? I tried using IGNORE, LAST_INSERT_ID(), and ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE but I cant figure out what works for a "ON DUPLICATE COLUMN UPDATE" scenario. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[mysql update if some values exists otherwise create a new entry](//stackoverflow.com/q/5755465/90527)", "[MySQL 'UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY' without a unique column?](//stackoverflow.com/q/3180913/90527)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must create unique index which will detect the duplication:

```sql
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX idx ON test (customer_id, textkey);
```

Now you can use `INSERT .. ODKU`:

```sql
INSERT INTO test (customer_id, textkey, value) VALUES
(1, 'text1', 'valueX'), 
(1, 'text3', 'valueY'), 
(1, 'text5', 'value5'), 
(1, 'text6', 'value6')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
value = VALUES(value);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6dcc351706f574f4c9f13c1fc95b9225

Comment: If we don't add a unique key and capitalize on the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause, would there be a way other than fetch and compare through a cursor in a sproc ?

Comment: @blabla_bingo Without unique key you must use 2 separate queries - INSERT and UPDATE. From the other side without this unique key the task makes no sense - in theory it is possible that newly inserted row interferes with 2 or more rows, and you have no criteria for to determine what row should be updated.

Comment: I'm afraid so. Thanks for the heads-up.